# How to do navigation durandal.js?

Tags: requirejs, single-page-application, durandal, sammy.js

i am trying to use durandal.js for single page architecture,

i already have application where i am loading all pages in div = old approach for single page architecture,

what i want to do is when i click on page i need to open hotspa pages,

for now i write something like this . www.xyz.com#/details,

where # details is my durandal view page!

when i put `<a>` herf ....#/details, i got error like this :
http://postimg.org/image/hoeu1wiz5/

but when i refresh with same url, it is working  fine, i am able to see view!

i do not know why i got this error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anything before version 2.0 of Durandal, you are getting this because in your Shell.js you are not defining router, or you have a bad definition of where the router module is, or possibly you are defining scripts in your index instead of 'requiring them' via require.js

1st - Check shell.js, at the top you should have a define function and it should say / do something like this, and should be exposing that to the view like so -

```
define(['durandal/plugins/router'], function (router) {

    var shell = {
        router: router
    };

    return shell;
};
```

2nd - Check and make sure the 'durandal/plugins/router' is point to the correct location in the solution explorer, in this case it is app > durandal > plugins > router.  If it is not or if there is no router you can add it using nuget.

3rd - Make sure you aren't loading scripts up in your index or shell html pages.  When using require.js you need to move any scripts you are loading into a require statement for everything to function properly.  The 'Mismatched anonymous define() module' error usually occurs when you are loading them elsewhere - http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch